# How to delete duplicate values from fields in SQL?

Tags: sql, duplicates

I have two tables (cd catalogs lets say) in my SQL DB. I want to put records from one table (that gets re-created nightly) into my main table. I only want to put items with a quantity greater than 0 into the main table. However, some items in the nightly table will have the same UPC barcode field as those in the main table. I do not want to put these in, provided those already in the main table have a quantity greater than 0. Otherwise I want all the entries with quantities greater than 0 to go from nightly to main table.

I simply can't wrap my head around how to do this. Of course I have it set up now so that everything with a quantity>0 gets copied to the main table, but then that means I can have duplicate listings for the same item that was already in the main table (duplicates based on UPC).

Anyone know how I can do this? My query as it stands:

```
INSERT INTO main ( id, title, artist, qty, barcode ) 
SELECT nightly.PID, 
       nightly.Title, 
       nightly.Artist, 
       nightly.QtyAvail, 
       nightly.UPC 
FROM nightly 
WHERE nightly.QtyAvail > 0;
```

Comment: just so you guys don't feel abandoned, I am implementing the query as suggested and will let you know how it goes (takes about half an hour :( )

Comment: actually now I am having trouble figuring out how to test this...

Answer (score 2):

```
insert into main ( id, title, artist, qty, barcode )
select
    n.PID, n.Title, n.Artist, n.QtyAvail, n.UPC 
from nightly as n
where
    n.QtyAvail > 0 and
    n.UPC not in (select T.barcode from main as T where T.qty > 0)
```

Comment: well yes, missed that from question. It should work anyway, because all items inserted into `main` from `nightly` already have `qty > 0`. It will not work, though, if there's a table `daily` and items inserted from that table with `qty < 0`. So changed an answer.

Comment: it seemed like this would work for me, but unfortunatley it ends up locking up the two tables and I have to go in and kill whatever processes are there and restart mysqld etc....

Comment: how many records do you have in your tables? do you have an index or primary key on `barcode` field in table `main`?

Comment: Hi Roman, the main table has probably around 5k records, the nightly table has around 30k records. I am not sure how to use indexes and primary keys so I will have to look it up. I am worried that changing either of those on my main table will affect other scripts that run using this table...